# Graph API calls to SharePoint Online is returning 504 responses and is taking more than usual time to complete the requests

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I have Http triggered Azure functions that interacts with SharePoint Online using Microsoft Graph SDK, the solution has been in production for couple of years - it creates documentsets/uploads files/updates metadata etc.,.  In past month or so it appears that the http calls are taking more than usual time to complete (and failing).  Below is one such example,

[image]
Few observations,

1. The Graph api calls are retried multiple times (exponential back-off) due to gateway timeout errors (504 response).
2. The first 3 Graph calls terminates around 30 seconds due to 504.
3. The last Graph call errors out with 409 - eTag mismatch error,

> resourceModified Message: The resource has changed since the caller
> last read it; usually an eTag mismatch
> Inner error:
> AdditionalData:
> date: 2023-03-01T11:21:53
> request-id: 570d092f-8980-44f1-a1a1-8d5185e6006a
> client-request-id: 570d092f-8980-44f1-a1a1-8d5185e6006a
> ClientRequestId: 570d092f-8980-44f1-a1a1-8d5185e6006a
> 4) We believe the number of calls are within the throttling threshold.

Questions:

1. Why are Graph API calls are terminating at 30th second?  Is this a default setting of the Graph SDK?  If so, is it recommended to change?
2. How to avoid eTag mismatch error while updating metadata, or, uploading files?  In our use case, all operations are replace of existing data.  (Note:  We have observed this error in scenarios where there is only one call targeting an item in SharePoint i.e., no real reason for mismatch.)
3. Is there a way to determine which applications is contributing to hitting throttling threshold?  As per my analysis there is no reason for SPO to throttle request (no. of requests is within the allowed limit as per the user licenses that our org. has), which team from Microsoft/SharePoint can assist us in troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue locally. For service issue, I recommend you raise a support case with Microsoft Graph, a Support Engineer will be able to assist you better. You can raise support ticket from:

http://aad.portal.azure.com or https://admin.microsoft.com/#/support/requests.

Hope this helps.

If the answer is helpful, please click Accept Answer and kindly upvote. If you have any further questions about this answer, please click Comment.